# How to disable one specific constraint for a size class?

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout, size-classes

Say I have a view whose width is 1/2 of the superview in portrait, and 1/3 of the superview in landscape, I thought I could set different multipliers for that constraint, but size class doesn't have this feature.

Then I found a solution in the following post, which says I have to disable and enable constraints for different size classes.

[Changing the multiplier of a constraint based on size class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227985/changing-the-multiplier-of-a-constraint-based-on-size-class)

I don't know how to do it. I only find a way of clearing all the constraints. But I don't want to rebuild all the constraints again. I just want change for the one constraint. If I delete that constraint in my current size class, it is also deleted in other size classes. Is there any way I can disable that constraint just for one specific size class?

Comment: select that particular constraint and click "Backspace" ! Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292514/how-do-i-easily-delete-a-constraint-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-6

Comment: @JennyJose Do you mean deleting that constraint? No I don't want to delete it. If I delete it, it is deleted for all the size classes. I just want to disable it (grey it out) for a specific size class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isActive` property.

As documentation says

> The active state of the constraint. You can activate or deactivate a
>   constraint by changing this property. Note that only active
>   constraints affect the calculated layout. If you try to activate a
>   constraint whose items have no common ancestor, an exception is
>   thrown. For newly created constraints, the active property is NO by
>   default. Activating or deactivating the constraint calls
>   addConstraint: and removeConstraint: on the view that is the closest
>   common ancestor of the items managed by this constraint. Use this
>   property instead of calling addConstraint: or removeConstraint:
>   directly

Comment: Can this property be set in interface builder? Or  I need to set it programmatically?

Comment: you can set it both in IB and code (in IB you will see 'Installed' checkBox

Comment: Didn't know 'installed' is for this function! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you delete a particular constraint in a particular size class

1.) select the specific size class you need

2.) Click on the view or uielement whose constraints you want to remove/add.

3.) All the constraints of that view or uielement is shown in the right side Attribute Inspector.

4.) Select the particular constraint you want to remove , which sets a blue border on that constraint.

5.) Then press Backspace.

This will delete it for that particular size class only.

This constraint now appears in grey on for that 
View Controller.